# Log an specific message

Tags: python, logging

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create_and_update_xlsx_sheets.py", line 183, in <module>
    create_and_update_worksheets()
  File "create_and_update_xlsx_sheets.py", line 178, in create_and_update_worksheets
    resize_columns(sheet)
  File "/home/Dave/.virtualenvs/NHL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 786, in __exit__
    self.close()
  File "/home/Dave/.virtualenvs/NHL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 790, in close
    return self.save()
  File "/home/Dave/.virtualenvs/NHL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 824, in save
    return self.book.save(self.path)
  File "/home/Dave/.virtualenvs/NHL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/openpyxl/workbook/workbook.py", line 345, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "/home/Dave/.virtualenvs/NHL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.py", line 266, in save_workbook
    writer.save(filename)
  File "/home/Dave/.virtualenvs/NHL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.py", line 248, in save
    self.write_data()
  File "/home/Dave/.virtualenvs/NHL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.py", line 93, in write_data
    archive.writestr(ARC_WORKBOOK, write_workbook(self.workbook))
  File "/home/Dave/.virtualenvs/NHL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/openpyxl/writer/workbook.py", line 91, in write_workbook
    active = get_active_sheet(wb)
  File "/home/Dave/.virtualenvs/NHL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/openpyxl/writer/workbook.py", line 61, in get_active_sheet
    raise IndexError("At least one sheet must be visible")
IndexError: At least one sheet must be visible
```

I am familiar with that kind of error. I pull CSV data from a certain website, but the subscription was expired, so I got that error. I would like to log an specific error that will tell me 'At least one sheet must be visible. Verify that your subscription with blabla.com is still active.' whenever I have that kind of error. How could I do such thing in python

Comment: Catch the `IndexError`, and show whatever message you'd like. See [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html).

Comment: `try:#...code that produces error sometimes` and `except IndexError:#...code that logs error` basically what @jonrsharpe said, use the Python tutorial. And if you don't know what the logging module in Python is I suggest you use that, [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) and [Good Tutorial by Fang](https://fangpenlin.com/posts/2012/08/26/good-logging-practice-in-python/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `try` and `except`.

```
try:
  # code that produces the error. ex:
  active = get_active_sheet(wb) # or
  raise IndexError("At least one sheet should be visible")
except IndexError as err:
  logger.error("An error occurred whilst pulling CSV from %s. Please ensure your connection to %s is still active.", website)
```

If you don't know how logger works check out [this tutorial by Fang](https://fangpenlin.com/posts/2012/08/26/good-logging-practice-in-python/). In the case your wondering more about Exception in Python check out the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) given by jonrsharpe in the comments.